# Cant access tag name inside SimpleXMLObject

Tags: php, xml

This is the print out from the variable `$baseTypeDerivedDataTypeRefModel` and is as far as I've got with getting the value I need. I need to extract the value int16, int64 etc from the SimpleXMLObject I've used `$baseTypeDerivedDataTypeRefModel[0]` and
`$baseTypeDerivedDataTypeRefModel->getName()` and a bunch of other stuff and cant get it to work, I know its probably something simple but its driving me crazy!

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [int16] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [range] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [min] => 1 [max] => 10 ) [ranges] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [subrange] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [min] => 1 [max] => 10 ) ) [multiplicationFactor] => 2 [resolution] => 2 ) ) 

SimpleXMLElement Object ( [int64] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [range] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [min] => 1 [max] => 10 ) [ranges] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [subrange] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [min] => 1 [max] => 10 ) ) [multiplicationFactor] => 2 [resolution] => 2 ) ) 

SimpleXMLElement Object ( [int16] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [range] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [min] => 1 [max] => 10 ) [ranges] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [subrange] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [min] => 1 [max] => 10 ) ) [multiplicationFactor] => 2 [resolution] => 2 ) ) 

SimpleXMLElement Object ( [uint8] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) ) 

SimpleXMLElement Object ( [int16] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [range] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [min] => 1 [max] => 10 ) [ranges] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [subrange] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [min] => 1 [max] => 10 ) ) [multiplicationFactor] => 2 [resolution] => 2 ) ) 

SimpleXMLElement Object ( [string] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) ) 


<derivedDataType name="DerivedIntDatatypeU16">
  <description>Random Desc </description>
  <baseType>
    <int16>
      <range>
        <min>1</min>
        <max>10</max>
      </range>
      <ranges>
        <subrange>
          <min>1</min>
          <max>10</max>
        </subrange>
      </ranges>
      <multiplicationFactor>2</multiplicationFactor>
      <resolution>2</resolution>
    </int16>
  </baseType>
</derivedDataType>
```

Comment: Could you post the XML you're using?

Comment: Added example xml below need to get a string "int16" by accessin the tag name and can only get as far as baseType

Comment: Added an answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you never know how many items "baseType" has (it is XML, after all), you could do this to get the name of the first item:

```
$xmlstring = '<derivedDataType name="DerivedIntDatatypeU16"> ... </derivedDataType>';
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstring);

// Cast the SimpleXMLObject as an array
$list = (array) $data->baseType;

// Reset the array pointer (so we know we're at the start of the array)
reset($list);

// Get the key name of the first element
$name = key($list);
```

This fetches the baseType list, casts it as an array and then gets the key of the first array element.

There might be (or most likely are) better ways to do this, but it works.